# How to make ajax call in magento admin form

Tags: magento2

In my magento admin form, I have added a category field. Based on the selection of category in category field an ajax call should be done.

```
$category = $fieldSet->addField(
            'category_id', 'select', [
                'name' => 'category_id',
                'label' => __('Category'),
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $this->_selectedCategories->toOptionArray(),
            ]
        );
```

I have set ajax call for that field

```
  $url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('homepage/ajax/getcategoryurl');

$category->setAfterElementHtml('
                        <script>
                        require([\'jquery\'], function($){
                        var customUrl = 
                    $("#category_id").on(\'change\', function () {                                       
                    $.ajax({
                        url: \''.$url.'\',
                        type: \'POST\',
                        data: {category_id: $(this).val(), form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
                        success: function (response) {
                            $("#url").val(response[\'content\']);
                        }
                    });
});
                        });
                        </script>
                    ');
```

Now how to set url for ajax call?

```
url: \'<?= $url; ?>\'
```

I am not getting controller call using this line. How to set $url as a ajax call url in script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your URL should not have a session key. Remove as below.

`$url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('homepage/ajax/getcategoryurl', ['_nosid' => true]);`

2. Correct the way to add a variable in the string.

`$category->setAfterElementHtml('
                        <script>
                        require([\'jquery\'], function($){
                        var customUrl = 
                    $("#category_id").on(\'change\', function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: \''.$url.'\',
                        type: \'POST\',
                        data: {category_id: $(this).val(), form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
                        success: function (response) {
                            $("#url").val(response[\'content\']);
                        }
                    });
                   });
                  });
                  </script>
                    ');`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this below way :

```
$category->setAfterElementHtml('
                        <script>
                        require([\'jquery\'], function($){
                        var url = '" . $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('homepage/ajax/getcategoryurl') . "';
                        var customUrl = 
                    $("#category_id").on(\'change\', function () {                                       
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: \'POST\',
                        data: {category_id: $(this).val(), form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
                        success: function (response) {
                            $("#url").val(response[\'content\']);
                        }
                    });
});
                        });
                        </script>
                    ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get URL using below code.

```
var url = '" . $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('homepage/ajax/getcategoryurl') . "';
```