# Ajax call issue in magento 2.2.6

Tags: ajax, magento2.2.6

My ajax call not working . It returns

```
"A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."
```

my ajax call code

```
function validateAuthorize()
{
    require([
        "jquery"
    ]

, function($){

var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl('path/ajaxcontroller', ['_nosid' => true]); ?>',
    showLoader: true,
    data: {name:name,email:email,form_key:'<?php echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>'},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
        jQuery('#message').html(result);
    }
});

}
```

controller

```
My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Ajaxcontroller\Index.php

<?php
    namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Ajaxcontroller;

    class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        protected $resultPageFactory;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            if($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){
                echo "Testing";
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Earlier ajax was working properly currently it returns

`A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later`

Comment: I already answered it. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/250735/59216

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ajax call in magento admin form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250730/how-to-make-ajax-call-in-magento-admin-form)

Comment: @MilindSingh , earlier my ajax code working , now it returns error 404 and display the message " A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later "

Comment: you should try posting `form_key` as a post param not in URL.

Comment: Have you updated the code as in the answer?

Comment: @MilindSingh , i place the form_key in params. still i face the same error

Comment: @MilindSingh, i will update my question with more codes

Comment: Did you add _nosid params?

Comment: @MilindSingh i used _nosid that also. still face the error

Comment: @MilindSingh i updated the code

Comment: @MilindSingh i got error "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later" along with status 404 .

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change ajax code like below way :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'admin/my_module/ajaxcontroller/index',
        showLoader: true,
        data: {name:name,email:email,form_key:'<?php echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>'},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result){
            jQuery('#message').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this is not working .I call ajax in dashboard page . in ajax call while i inspect it call below url"http://localhost/magento/adminpage/path/dashboard/index/key/b19d10f83e438bdeb93ad292ce1607ddf2600cb178223767d0a614b5da445a94/admin/my_module/ajaxcontroller/index?isAjax=true "

Comment: This is not call that controller  ajaxcontroller/index controller

Comment: just use this code for base admin url : <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Backend\Helper\Data')->getHomePageUrl(); ?>

Comment: Then combine => my_module/ajaxcontroller/index

Comment: You can accept and upvote answer if it's useful for you :)

Comment: Error solved. error happens because of namespace issue in controller  . it is working now.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)